# The sky was full of stars

Tags: phrase-requests

I want a phrase that I can use instead of "full of" in this sentence:

***The black sky night was full of bright stars.***

Does "teem with" work?

***The black sky night was teeming with bright stars.***

And what is an adjective I could use to describe such sky? Star---(adjective) sky

Comment: Teeming is an acceptable adjective. It will draw a minor metaphor alluding to a school of fish in most readers. Consider it to mean densely packed with a number of whatever kind of thing the subject is. Otherwise have you consulted a dictionary?

Comment: Things that teem usually move, or behave in a lively manner. Some dictionaries give 'swarm' as one of the definitions.

Comment: How about star-spangled?

Comment: @AntonSherwood Only if you want to make a comparison with the American flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely say the sky is teeming with stars.
I'm having trouble finding a phrase other than star-filled sky. Star-laden sky, maybe, but it's not great. You didn't ask this, so please ignore it if you want. But, is it really a black sky night if the sky is full of stars?

Comment: You are right. Black may not work. I thought of laden but I thought that is more apt to describe a tree.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I couldn't figure out why I wasn't happy with star-laden. It's because it implies weight, like fruit hanging from a tree.

Comment: Star-sprinkled?

Comment: Star-studded used to be common before the rise of the cinema, which seems to have taken over the primary meaning, but it is still used in the way the OP means.

Answer (score 0):

The sky certainly wasn't *full* of stars.

How about moving the adjective?

> The **night** sky was **bright** with stars.

Comment: I found this in a dictionary: a night sky spangled with stars

Comment: Is this correct? : Star-spangled (adjective) night sky

Comment: That seems very American, them having coined that phrase for the flag.

Comment: So, is it okay? For example in this sentence: He was gazing into the star-spangled night sky.

Comment: Well, this answer gives my suggestion, so I am not going to say "use something else." I already commented that a "star-spangled sky" sounds like the American flag. You've asked me three times now...

Comment: You cannot reasonably quote an anthem without expecting many readers to think that's what you're doing. The reason your sky was starry may have been your location, away from city lights, and you can say the 'countryside sky'. Also, the sky may have been starlit, start-flooded, or resplendent with stars.